# How to get latitude and longitude of map in using Android google mapV2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am looking for latitude and longitude values of **top right corner of mapView**  using Android google maps V2. I posted similar question on the same issue, but no use.

I wrote code for this,but getting zero values.

**please check my code:**

```
MapView mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LatLngBounds bounds = mapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
            LatLng topright = bounds.northeast;
            double toprgt_latitude = topright.latitude;

            Log.d("top lat", "" + toprgt_latitude);//getting zero values.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.northeast after map is shown.

```
LatLng corner;

mapView.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
    corner = mapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.northeast;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LatLng currentposition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
sys.out.println(""+location.getLatitude()""+location.getLongitude());
```